# Trying to inherit views from another module and make some changes (Odoo)

Tags: python, odoo

odoo.tools.convert.ParseError: while parsing /home/almas/odoo-dev/odoo/custom/absence_mod/views/maintenance.xml:4, near

```
    <record id="hr_equipment_request_view_kanban_inherit" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">maintenance.request.inherited</field>
        <field name="model">maintenance.request</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="maintenance.hr_equipment_request_view_kanban"/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <field name="category_id" position="after">
                <field name="maintenance_type"/>
            </field>
        </field>
    </record>
```

It has to be some typing error

Comment: There should be more Error information in the log. Please try to add it and also try to add more information on how you've extended model `maintenance.request`.

Answer (score 1):

replace it by this :

```
<record id="hr_equipment_request_view_kanban_inherit" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">maintenance.request.inherited</field>
        <field name="model">maintenance.request</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="maintenance.hr_equipment_request_view_kanban"/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <xpath expr="//field[@name='category_id']" position="after">
                <field name="maintenance_type"/>
            </xpath>
        </field>
    </record>
```

Comment: thank you for the help, i already fixed it. I forgot to add depende: 'maintenance'. do not judge me